# Why is the Mazur swindle named so?

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology, math-history, knot-theory

Often results or techniques in mathematics are called 'theorems'. Sometimes they are called 'tricks'. In no other context have I seen a result called a 'swindle'. Is there a historical reason for this trick being called a swindle?

Comment: "swindle" implies loss of money. Not that I have even heard of the use of that word related to any mathematical results.

Comment: This is just speculation (and not in my areas of expertise), but the Mazur swindle is a particularly devious trick. Any argument based on the equation $X = X + (Y+X) + (Y+X) + \ldots = 0$ with $X,Y$ nonzero objects of some kind seems false intuitively. When it's applied in contexts where it's valid, it almost feels like you're being cheated of a "real" proof. Now that said, it might also be someone lost a bet to Mazur about something related to this technique! `:)`

Comment: I was going to guess a similar, but more charitable version: perhaps Mazur, in describing the idea, said something like "Now when you see this, you're going to think that you've been swindled..." to warn his audience of the cleverness/deviousness of what was forthcoming.

Comment: The term "Jeans swindle" is used to refer to a technique in the work of James Jeans, though that's in astronomy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earliest use of the term ‘swindle’ for this little ploy, this ruse, appears to be in H. Bass. [*Big Projective Modules Are Free*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255637479), Illinois J. Math. **7**(1) (1963), 24–31. He writes:

> *Our method relies on two basic tools. … The second is an elegant little swindle, observed several years ago by Eilenberg, and which might well have sprung from the brow of Barry Mazur.*

This is in reference to the 1959 and 1961 papers of B. Mazur, namely [*On the structure of certain semi-groups of spherical knot classes*](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1959__3__19_0/), Publications Mathématiques de l'IHÉS **3** (1959), 19–27, and [*On embeddings of spheres*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485889174), Acta Mathematica **105**(1–2) (1961), 1–17.

As for why Bass chose the term ‘swindle’… Well, the trick does appear to be quite the swindle, quite the sham, and maybe almost a scandal indeed! For surely you would feel cheated if someone told you something like
$$1=1+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+\dots=(1-1)+(1-1)+\dots=0.$$